# How to get the unique pairs from the given data frame column with file handling?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

sample data from dataframe:
[image: sample data from dataframe]

## Pairs

````
(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)
(6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)
(2, 12), (12, 3), (3, 4), (4, 12), (12, 12)

    ```
    
        new_col = []
            for e in content.Pairs:
            new_col.append(list(dict.fromkeys(e)))
            content['Unique'] = new_col
    
    ```
````

## output expected is unique pairs from Pair column like this:

```
(8, 8),(6, 7),(7, 6),(7, 7),(2, 12) so on
```

## what I am getting is this result when trying the above code:

## Unique

```
['8', '']
['6', '7', '']
['2', '12', '3', '4', '']
```

what is the issue with the data if I am doing with manual data then it's working why not in the data frame

Comment: You've posted the exact same question twice. I recommend you delete this one and anyone thinking of commenting should do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60056339/how-to-get-the-unique-pairs-from-the-given-data-frame-column-in-pandas

Comment: Instead of a list, simply use a set. The set type enforces unique values and the easiest way to do that is `set(<yourListWithDupesHere>)`. (the only negative point in this approach is that the type in the set needs to be hashable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **set** method:

```
data = (((8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)),
  ((6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)),
  ((2, 12), (12, 3), (3, 4), (4, 12), (12, 12)))

uniques = []

for col in data:
  for unique in list(set(col)):
    uniques.append(unique)

for x in uniques:
  print(x)
```

**OR**:

```
data = (((8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8)),
  ((6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7)),
  ((2, 12), (12, 3), (3, 4), (4, 12), (12, 12)))

uniques = []

for col in data:
  uniques += [unique for unique in list(set(col))]

for x in uniques:
  print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set() method to remove duplicates from the list of tuples.

```
 >>> items = [(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 8),
(6, 7), (7, 7), (7, 7), (7, 6), (6, 7),
(2, 12), (12, 3), (3, 4), (4, 12), (12, 12)]
>>> set_items = set(items)
>>> set_items
{(6, 7), (7, 6), (12, 12), (7, 7), (8, 8), (4, 12), (2, 12), (3, 4), (12, 3)}
```

Comment: it's not working I got this error/ ValueError: Length of values does not match the length of the index ...